# Filtering traffic between IP alias

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have issues filtering traffic with two hosts and a firewall between them.
Each of these three hosts have only one NIC on which they can communicate on a network say 10.10.0.0/16. I'd like to add another network but I have a constraint that do not allow me to add another NIC.

My idea was to work with ip aliasing. So in order to achieve this I set up each NIC of each host to have multiple address like that :

```
host0 : eth0 = 10.10.0.1/16
               192.168.0.1/24

router : eth0 = 10.10.0.2/16
               192.168.0.254/24
               192.168.1.254/24

host1 : eth0 = 10.10.0.3/16
               192.168.1.1/24
```

As a pictures often speaks better than words, I have this :

```
HOST0                 ROUTER                   HOST1
   |                    |                         |
   ------------------------------------------------
10.10.0.1           10.10.0.2                  10.10.0.3
```

And I'd like to simulate this (with only one NIC) :

```
HOST0--------------------ROUTER------------------HOST1
192.168.0.1            0.254  1.254              1.1
```

I configured each host with `ip` command :

```
ip add dev eth0 192.168.0.*
```

then add route with ip route.

My problem is that a ping from host0 to host1 is going well even if I drop every packet on `router` with `iptables` which indicates that the ping might not go through router but prefers going directly instead. 
I took a tcpdump trace which shows host0's ping going straight to host1.

I have the feeling that it shouldn't not work like that but I can't figure it out.

Here the tcpdump trace :

```
52:54:00:00:00:00 > 52:54:00:00:00:02, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.0.1 >     192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 4309, seq 3, length 64
52:54:00:00:00:02 > 52:54:00:00:00:00, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 4309, seq 3, length 64
52:54:00:00:00:00 > 52:54:00:00:00:02, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 4309, seq 4, length 64
52:54:00:00:00:02 > 52:54:00:00:00:00, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 4309, seq 4, length 64
52:54:00:00:00:00 > 52:54:00:00:00:02, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 4309, seq 5, length 64
52:54:00:00:00:02 > 52:54:00:00:00:00, IPv4, length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 4309, seq 5, length 64
```

Comment: Please post the tcpdump with MAC addresses shown, because a ping going from 192.168.0.1/24 to 192.168.1.1/24 is impossible without using the router.

Comment: To address the original problem: If you want to force communication between Host0 and Host1 to use Router, why don't you use two [VLANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN), one between Host0 and Router, and one between Router and Host1? Then you'll have two VLAN network interfaces on Router, and you can proceed as usual.